# Probability of winning with multiple tickets in multiple draws

Tags: probability, combinations, lotteries

Unfortunately, after hours of searching I was unable to find an answer to the following scenario:

Let's assume I play five unique combinations in a weekly 6/49 lottery, where the chance of matching all six numbers in this one draw will be 5/13983816 or *p*=0.0000017878.

However, how would I calculate the winning probability if I played *the same number of tickets in 52 weekly draws* (that is, a total of 260 unique lines altogether).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The author determined the probability to win in one draw. I would consider this as an effort!

Comment: @Peter Thanks! I wish I could figure how to insert a decent formula to show my own prior attempts but struggling with it on this my first posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that you do not win with this draw $n$ times in a row is $$(1-\frac{5}{13983816})^n$$ hence the probability that you win at least once is $$1-(1-\frac{5}{13983816})^n$$ If you plug in $n=52$ , you get $1.859\cdot 10^{-5}$ , which is very near to $\frac{260}{13983816}$, but the exact value is in fact a bit smaller.

Comment: You must have read my mind :-)  Although I couldn't show my workings satisfactorily (I'll get there eventually !) I was thinking along the lines of your approximation (5x52)/13983816 but it didn't quite feel right somehow.

Comment: If $pn$ is small, then $$(1-p)^n\approx 1-pn$$ justifying the approximation in the given case.